# Unable to filter using html input value in D3JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Would like to know if I could use two html input elements can be used to filter out d.rating and d.value(see code below).Also could I replace the csv dynamically if I use a dropdown and allow the user to select which csv they want to see the visualization for.

https://plnkr.co/edit/WgGs5bcHUP3AmjncivPM?p=preview

```html
<html>
<head>

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>



<body>
  <input id="myInput" type="number">

<div class="container">




  <svg width="1250" height="1080"></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      width = +svg.attr("width");

  var format = d3.format(",d");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var pack = d3.pack()
      .size([width, width])
      .padding(1.5);
      
      var myInput;
d3.select("#myInput").on("change", function(){
    myInput = this.value;


  d3.csv("austin_fsq.csv", function(d) {
    d.sno = +d.sno;
    if (d.sno && d.rating>=9&&d.value < myInput) return d;
  }, function(error, classes) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
        .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .each(function(d) {
          if (id = d.data.id) {
            var id, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
            d.id = id;
            d.package = id.slice(0, i);
            d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
          }
        });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack(root).leaves())
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.package); });

    node.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
      .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; });

    node.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", function(d) { return "url(#clip-" + d.id + ")"; })
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(function(d) { return d.class.split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g); })
      .enter().append("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", function(d, i, nodes) { return 13 + (i - nodes.length / 2 - 0.5) * 10; })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });

    node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.id + "\n" + format(d.value); });
  });
})

   </script>
 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to convert the input value to a number before using it in the `if` condition (with the unary operator plus, for instance):

```
if (d.sno && d.rating >= 9 && d.value < +myInput) return d;
    //converting to a number -----------^
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/wmFIxN6ZydAxLhVDSWNf?p=preview

**EDIT**: avoinding using the row function.

Right now, you're using the row function to filter your data. This has the unwanted effect of loading and parsing the CSV file *after* the input being entered, which can lead to some delay (never a good user experience).

An alternative is filtering the data after loading and parsing it. This is the logic:

```
//d3.csv loads and parses the CSV file
d3.csv("austin_fsq.csv", function(d) {
    d.sno = +d.sno;
    return d;
}, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    //check the input inside d3.csv
    d3.select("#myInput").on("change", function() {
        myInput = this.value;
        var classes = data.filter(d => d.value < myInput && d.rating >= 9);
        //on change, call a function to draw the results
        draw(classes);
    });

    //the function to draw the results here
    function draw(classes) {
        //code here...
    }
});
```

Actually, if you use this approach, you can easily solve the second problem in your question, which is getting both input values:

```
var inputs = {};

d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function() {
    inputs[this.id] = +this.value;
    if (inputs.myValue && inputs.myRating) {
        var classes = data.filter(d => d.value < inputs.myValue && d.rating >= inputs.myRating);
        draw(classes);
    }
})
```

Here is the plunker showing it, you can set both values and you can see that there is almost no delay after you hit "enter" for the second one: https://plnkr.co/edit/AjVBK3rTOF5aI4eDDbV5?p=preview

Comment: Can the bounty be on the question for how to use two input values and also could I select the csv file from a list in dropdown. So if the user wants to select it Dallas they can use that csv.

Comment: Yes, sure. In that case, edit the question to address only this problem, because the issue with the input value was solved.

Comment: No worries. I still don't understand why do you want to check the input inside the row function. The user will have to wait for the CSV to load *after* he hits enter, and the delay (depending on the size of the file and the connection speed) can mean a bad user experience. A better approach, as I told you before, would be loading the whole CSV, dropping the row function. Then, after the input value being received, you just filter the data and call the drawing function with the filtered data.

Comment: I am just starting with d3js and this was picked from one of the examples I went through. Let me see the other way which you explained and see how to do that . I do agree with your logic of the delay in case where the csv files are too big.

Comment: @SNT check the edit. I changed your code's structure and put the second input for the ratings, so your second problem is fixed. Regarding your third problem I reckon you should ask another question: It's never a good practice here at S.O. asking about several issues in a single question.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I am working on the csv problem myself. Thanks for helping me with the two input solution.Sure if I get stuck I will open a separate thread.